# Como preguntar al usuario si quiere consultar mediante messagebuttons

Tags: vb.net

tengo este codigo para realizar una busqueda a mi base de datos y llenarme un textbox el codigo funciona pero le indique en el codigo que sino llegase a leer que en un bloque catch que me muestre unos messagebuttons YesNo y que realizara determinadas acciones sucede que si no lee simplemente lo que hace es que no ejecuta la busqueda, no da error , no detiene el programa ni muestra los messagebuttons simplemente no hace nada, pero si digito un codigo que si exista funciona correctamente.

```
Private Sub btnbuscar2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbuscar2.Click
    Try
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=SAMUELSUSANA; Initial catalog=poovb;integrated security=true")
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from tblsuplidores where Suplidor_ID='" & txtcodigosuplidor.Text & "'", con)
        D_table = New DataTable
        con.Open()

        If (txtcodigosuplidor.Text = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Debe Pasar El Parametro Del Codigo del Suplidor Para Realizar La Busqueda.", "Hola, Disculpa", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            txtcodigosuplidor.Focus()

        Else
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If (dr.Read) Then
                txtsuplidor.Text = dr("Nombre").ToString
                txtcantidad.Enabled = True
                txtcodigosuplidor.Enabled = False
                btnbuscar2.Enabled = False
                txtcantidad.Focus()
            Else
            End If
        End If
        con.Close()
        dr.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim Respuesta As DialogResult
        Respuesta = MessageBox.Show("Desea Consultar Por un Suplidor?", "Busqueda Erronea.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        If (Respuesta = DialogResult.Yes) Then
            Consultasuplidores.Show()
        Else
            txtcodigosuplidor.Clear()
            txtcodigosuplidor.Focus()
        End If

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: A ver si entendí. Primero, validas que al menos el Textbox `txtcodigosuplidor` tenga un valor para realizar la búsqueda, si tiene un valor lo realiza y si no muestras el `MessageBox.Show`. Por último, al realizar la búsqueda si tienes resultados entonces recuperas el valor en el Textbox `txtsuplidor` en caso contrario (no encuentre algún resultado) debe ejecutarse el código que está dentro del `catch`. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: si exactamente asi pero no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

Explicando el código que realizaste (solo tienes un error de lógica):

Al realizar `dr.Read`, estás consultan el primer registro del resultado de tu consulta y será `true` en caso consiga un registro, en caso de no encontrar ningún resultado será `false`.

Solo entraría en la excepción en caso hubiera un ***error de ejecución*** dentro del bloque `Try`, pero tu no tienes ningún error.

---

Para considerarlo solo sería necesario:

```
If (dr.Read) Then
    txtsuplidor.Text = dr("Nombre").ToString
    txtcantidad.Enabled = True
    txtcodigosuplidor.Enabled = False
    btnbuscar2.Enabled = False
    txtcantidad.Focus()
Else            
    Dim Respuesta As DialogResult
    Respuesta = MessageBox.Show("Desea Consultar Por un Suplidor?", "Busqueda Erronea.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    If (Respuesta = DialogResult.Yes) Then
        Consultasuplidores.Show()
    Else
        txtcodigosuplidor.Clear()
        txtcodigosuplidor.Focus()
    End If                              
End If
```

Comment: o si verdad ,, gracias